# "Would agree" vs "would have agreed"

Tags: phrases, expressions, sentence

> Did I really believe she would agree?

and

> Did I really believe she would have agreed?

What's the difference between the two? Is one more common/grammatically correct than the other?

Comment: Neat question! Because of the complexity of the elements being juxtaposed (past tense, questioning, irrealis, belief, agreement) I think most people would struggle to distinguish the different possibilities in their mind. And since we mainly do that with words ([Sapir–Whorf hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_relativity), and all that), I don't think you could necessarily rely on the average native speaker to either produce or understand the "right" form or meaning. But your #2 is *much* less common (and much more complex, I feel).

Comment: Both versions are fine. The contrast between them might be similar to the contrast between the pair of: *"I thought she would know better"* vs *"I thought she would have known better"*. A native English speaker would usually have a feel as to which version would be preferable in a specific situation, but would probably have difficulty in explaining the grammatical reasoning. Another tag for you to search for related info is "backshifting".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They convey slightly different meanings:

1) Did I really believe (then that) she would agree (with me now [or more recently])?

vs

2) Did I really believe (then) that she would have agreed (with me back then)?

Sometimes you hear the first one used like the second. This is probably a result of people getting lazy in conversation and saying "Did I really believe that she would agree?" instead of "Did I really believe that she would've agreed?" The word "would've" is really cumbersome to pronounce so just leaving the (have) and (-ed) implicit is more instinctive in casual conversation if there is context to support the story.

Answer (score 2):

OP's second version is cumbersome, ambiguous, and probably wouldn't be used at all. Belief and agreement are slippery concepts when we've got complex tense interactions like this, so I'll recast to something I find easier to deal with...

> 1: Did I know she would go?
>    2: Did I know she would have gone?

or more simply, since the fact of it being framed as a question doesn't affect the "awkward" part...

> 3: I knew [that] she would go
>    4: I knew [that] she would have gone

It's then much easier to see that in #3 what I knew (and what OP wondered if he believed) was that *she would go at some later time* (***after*** the knowing/wondering).

But what I knew in #4 could be either of two possibilities (both grammatically credible)...

> 4a: ...that she had ***already gone*** (as in *"Back in the 60s I would have been just a teenager"*)
>    4b: ...that if things were different she'd have gone, but for some reason ***she didn't go*** (and may never)

It's a bit more tricky to transfer the *grammar* of 4a/b to the *semantics* of OP's two versions.

To make sense of the 4a interpretation we have to assume her (already-made) agreement was with *someone else* (I could hardly be wondering whether she'd already agreed with *me*).

A simple "reason" that works for the 4b interpretation is to suppose that *I never in fact asked her*, which is why she didn't actually agree. But of course there could be any number of other reasons.

---

Regarding which form is more *common*, here are some relevant counts from Google Books,...

> *"I thought she would know"* [18,700 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=copious%20-%22copious%20amounts%22%20-%22copious%20hair%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22I%20thought%20she%20would%20know%22&tbm=bks)
>    *""I thought she would have known""* [2 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=copious%20-%22copious%20amounts%22%20-%22copious%20hair%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22I%20thought%20she%20would%20have%20known%22&tbm=bks)
>    *"I believed she would take [something]"* [956 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=copious%20-%22copious%20amounts%22%20-%22copious%20hair%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22I%20believed%20she%20would%20take%22&tbm=bks)
>    *"I believed she would have taken [it]"* [1 result](https://www.google.com/search?q=copious%20-%22copious%20amounts%22%20-%22copious%20hair%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22I%20believed%20she%20would%20have%20taken%22&tbm=bks)

Comment: For 4a, is it a backshifted version of "I know [that] she will have gone."? @FumbleFingers

Comment: @Zhanlong: I'm not sure what "backshifting" means in the context of a complex "conditional" usage where *she will have gone* effectively means *she **went***. In *semantic* terms, it's already "past tense". Superficially, the *will* part refers to a hypothetical "future knowledge" of what ***will** become apparent* upon further investigation, but that rationale is kinda weakened by the present tense verb ***know***. Whatever - I assume you understand the two different possible meanings represented by 4a/4b.

Comment: 4b is easy. 4a is a little bit confusing. you say "Back in the 60s I would have been just a teenager". Why not "Back in the 60s I was just a teenager"? Since it's not a hypothetical usage, how is this usage derived?

Comment: @Zhanlong: Of course it's confusing! I assume that's why OP has asked about it! The bottom line is it *is* a "hypothetical/irrealis" usage - it really does mean *this is what we **will** find IF we **look** into it* (or *this is what we **would** find IF we **looked/were to look** into it*). To native speakers such usages are perfectly natural, even in contexts where some other element implies that *we already **have** looked into it*. Thus, *"I know that I **would have been** a teenager in the 60s"* is a perfectly credible alternative to *"I know that I **was** a teenager in the 60s"*.

Comment: When one expresses his opinion, is "would have + pp" always an apt alternative to "past form"? When is one preferred over the other? Please help. @FumbleFingers

Comment: @Zhanlong: I think you're getting things mixed up. When expressing an opinion, *"I would have thought X"* is a slightly more "hesitant" way of saying *"I **think** X"*, not *"I **thought** X"*. It's obviously a difficult area for learners, because we have lots of questions on this topic - for example, [this one](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5714/).

Comment: As some grammar books say, "I would think X" is a more "hesitant" or less assertive way of saying "I think X". But you say "I would have thought X" is. I feel confused. This is my personal thinking: "I would have thought X" if you had asked me; "I would think X" if you asked me, so "would have thought X" refers to past, irrealis thought; "would think X" refers to present, irrealis thought. What do you think of my idea? Do I mix it with another usage? @FumbleFingers

Comment: @Zhanlong: English is very relaxed about whether or how verb forms relate to past-present-future. *"I go tomorrow"* is perfectly acceptable, and *"Last night he goes to the pub again"* is common in casual speech, for example. By the same token, *"I would think X"* and *"I would have thought X"* can both mean *"I think X"*. You should post a question on this specific matter if you can't find an earlier question dealing with it.

Comment: Thx. On your suggestion, maybe I'll post one. Before I do, I wonder why you say _"I would have thought X" is a slightly more "hesitant" way of saying "I think X", not "I thought X"._ I don't think it refers to a casual talk. What's the logic of it? @FumbleFingers

Comment: I know normal speech is not as strict or precise as the rules of grammar, but I would think it is best to know the mechanism of these rules before I can have a casual attitude towards them.

Comment: @Zhanlong: The reason *"I would think so"* is less "committed" than *"I think so"* is because the "irrealis" aspect places the assertion somewhere other than "here and now". Using the superficially "past" form *"I would have thought so"* simply places it even further away, (metaphorically - it's actually nothing to do with past/present as such). For native speakers, it's just another natural way of "distancing" the speaker from an assertion - which can be taken even further by saying *"**One** would have thought so"* - to avoid even mentioning ***I/me (the person here now speaking)***.

Comment: Thx for explaining the hidden logic. It's far more intuitive than a plain rule to be memorized! If all books on grammar or usage could be written in this way, it would benifit ESL learners a lot more.

Comment: Sorry to bother you. PEU gives an example: *I'm surprised you didn't like the film. I would have thought it was just your kind of thing.* I tend to think "I would have thought" here means "I thought", not "I think". Am I right? @FumbleFingers

Comment: @Zhanlong: We could do with a ["canonical post"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/) on conditionals/modals. People might sometimes even say *"I would think you'd like that kind of film"* (dragging the focus into the present, and thus pressurising the addressee to *explain* why he doesn't/didn't like it). Using ***would*** there is just a politeness thing, placing "distance" between the interlocutors themselves and the "delicate" subject being spoken of (a clash of tastes or preperceptions).